# getting this function to loop properly

Tags: c++, loops

I am making a function to give the time taken to travel from Chicago to a certain city.  I am trying to make it loop so that when the user chooses the city, it gives the time taken and loops back up to ask the main question and let the user choose another city.  I am also including an option where they can exit the loop.  What I have so far is this:

```
    main()
    {
      TripInfo trip;
      int choice;

      do
        {
          cout << "You are in Chicago. Where would you like to drive?\n"
               << "Enter number of city\n" << "1. New York City\n" << "2. Boston\n"
               << "3. Philadelphia\n" << "4. Toronto\n" << "5. Washington D.C.\n"
               << "6. Miami\n" << "7. Indianapolis\n" << "8. Los Angeles\n"
               << "9. San Fransisco\n" << "10. Phoenix\n" << "11. EXIT" << endl;
          cin >> choice;
          if(choice = 11)
            {
              cout << "Program terminated." << endl;
              break;
            }

          trip.setDistance(choice);
          cout << "The distance from Chicago to " << trip.getDestination() << " is "
               << trip.getDistance() << endl;

          trip.setRate();
          cout << "The speed you will be travelling at from Chicago to "
               << trip.getDestination() << " is " << trip.getRate() << endl;

          trip.calculateTime();
          cout << "The time it will take to travel from Chicago to "
               << trip.getDestination() << " at " << trip.getRate()
               << " miles per hour will be:\n " << trip.getTime() << " hours."
               << endl;
        }
    }
```

The problem is in the output.  Even though there is a condition for the if statement and if choice is not 11, the function still prints "Program terminated.".  How do I fix this so that if choice = 11, the program terminates, and if choice is not 11, it continues and loops through the various functions again and again until choice is chosen to be 11?

Comment: That isn't valid C++ code, there's important bits missing.

Comment: Also, turn up the warnings on your compiler

Comment: `do` must always have a matching `while`. In order to get the help you want, you need to be careful that your code contains no errors other than what you are asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `choice == 11`. A single `=` sign causes 11 to be assigned to choice (and that assignment evaluates to true).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `==` to compare for equality; `=` is assignment, returning the value assigned, and nonzero is interpreted as true.

A convention I've seen to try to prevent this issue is to *put the constant on the left*.  The following block of code will produce a compiler error:

```
      if(11 = choice)
        {
          cout << "Program terminated." << endl;
          break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(choice = 11)
```

means you assign `choice` a value of `11`, and test for if value is non-zero, which is true. It should be

```
if(choice == 11)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct format is

```
if(choice == 11) {
--- }
```

`=` is used for assignment and `==` is used for checking the equality.

Also you have to give a `while`condition at the end of `do` statement for checking the condition to enter in the loop again.

Answer (score 0):

if (choice = 13) {......}

the expression is true ever, assignment expression value is var's value, above is choice, the assignment expression is 13, 13 is true.

you can write 13 = choice to protect error by compiler, but i suggest you write choice == 13 ways, because this ways will understand well.